# How to check in rows is older then 2 hours Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Im working with Laravel 5.0 and im trying to delete all rows in a table where the `created_at` is older then 3 hours.

How id it possible to check the age of the `created_at` with Carbon?

```
$time = Carbon::now()->subHour(3);
$photos = Photos::where('created_at','<=',$time);
if($photos){
echo 'older then 3 hours';
}else
echo 'not older then 3 hours';
}
```

This code Always echo 'older then 3 hours', even if i change the´created_at date in MySql table.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong. Tell us what is wrong. What's your problem?

Comment: i will edit the code above and show you

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems:

- You didn't actually fetch the results (`->get()`)
- `$photos` is a Collection object that always evaluates to `true`, even if it is an empty collection.

Solution

```
$time = Carbon::now()->subHour(3);
$photos = Photos::where('created_at','<=',$time)->get();
if($photos->count()){
    echo 'older than 3 hours';
} else {
    echo 'not older than 3 hours';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually running the query - your `if($photos)` is simply returning true because it is an object (the query builder).

Change to:

```
$time = Carbon::now()->subHour(3);
$photos = Photos::where('created_at','<=',$time)->get();
if (!$photos->isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be something like this:

```
$photos = Photos::where(DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, 'created_at', NOW())"), '>', 3)->get();
foreach($photos as $photo) {
    // echo $photo->created_at . PHP_EOL;
}
```